# How to achieve automated margin functionality in Less instead of jQuery

Tags: jquery, less

I have a function written in jQuery that automates the `margin-bottom` or `padding-bottom` (conditionally) of a table. Basically it negates the effect of the table cells' borders pushing down the page, keeping the [vertical rhythm](http://24ways.org/2006/compose-to-a-vertical-rhythm/) intact. **Instead of using JS to do this, I believe I should be able to with Less and CSS instead.**

The condition (if-statement) is based on the number of rows (and thus borders, plus one more) in the table. Since my "[magic number](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/14/technical-web-typography-guidelines-and-techniques/#tt-rhythm)" is 24 (24px is the vertical rhythm unit), if the table has (0,11)∪(24,35)∪… borders, the function will make the `margin-bottom` negative and pull the rest of the page up. However if the table has (12,23)∪(36,47)∪… borders, it will add to the `padding-bottom`, pushing the rest of the page down to the next vertical rhythm unit. This is all operating under the assumption that each horizontal border in the table is 1px. **Extra credit if you can generalize the pattern to work for thicker borders.**

Here's my function in jQuery:

```
/*
Algorithm:
for each table:
take the number of rows (x)
add 12
mod 24
subtract 12
negate.
function notation: g(x) = -(f(x+12)-12) where f(x) = MOD(x,24)
function transformation: MOD(x,24) translated left 12 and down 12, then flipped over the x-axis.
if g(x) <= 0, then margin-bottom that number
else, padding-bottom that number.
*/
$('table').each(function () {
    var n_rows = 0;
    $(this).find('tr').each(function () {
        n_rows++;
    });
    n_rows++; // once more for the last border
    var btm = -(((n_rows + 12) % 24) - 12);
    if (btm <= 0) {$(this).css('margin-bottom',btm);}
    else          {$(this).css('padding-bottom',btm);}
});
```

Here's what I have so far in my Less:

```
table {
    counter-reset: nrows;
    tr {
        counter-increment: nrows;
    }
    counter-increment: nrows; // once more for the last border
//  @btm: -(((nrows + 12) % 24) - 12);
//  if (@btm <= 0) {
//      margin-bottom: @btm;
//  } else {
//      padding-bottom: @btm;
//  }
}
```

Help me out here?

Comment: how are you planning to count rows via css ?

Comment: CSS counters are not defined for anything except the `content` value and list counters, not even in the level 3 counter styles modules. You won't be able to use them with any other property.

Comment: @ProllyGeek with `tr {counter-increment: nrows;}`

Comment: Well, the problem with `counter-increment` is that it is calculated by the browser *after* your less code compiles to css. So Less can't use this value. (Or in general, Less has no knowledge of your HTML so it's impossible if your formula relies on the number of table rows).

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question well, you can use the [nth-child pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

**less**

```
.childern(@i){
.margins(@i) when (@i > 0) and (@i < @number/2) {
.margins((@i - 1));
tr:nth-child(@{number}n+@{i})
{
margin-bottom: ~"-@{i}px";
}
}
.margins(@i) when (@i > (@number/2-1)) {
.margins((@i - 1));
tr:nth-child(@{number}n+@{i})
{
padding-bottom: unit(@number - @i,px);
}
}
.margins(@i);
}
table {
.childern(@number);
}
@number: 24;
```

The above Less code will compile into CSS code as follows:

```
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 1) {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 2) {
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 3) {
  margin-bottom: -3px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 4) {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 5) {
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 6) {
  margin-bottom: -6px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 7) {
  margin-bottom: -7px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 8) {
  margin-bottom: -8px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 9) {
  margin-bottom: -9px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 10) {
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 11) {
  margin-bottom: -11px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 12) {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 13) {
  padding-bottom: 11px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 14) {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 15) {
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 16) {
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 17) {
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 18) {
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 19) {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 20) {
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 21) {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 22) {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 23) {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
table tr:nth-child( 24n + 24) {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```